# How many ways are there to give 16 identical balloons and 11 different toys to 9 different children so that each child gets at least 1 toy?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

Prompt:

> How many ways are there to give 16 identical balloons and 11 different toys to 9 different children so that each child gets at least 1 toy?

Here's what I tried doing

Ways to distribute 11 toys to children so each child get's at least one toy, **Remove 9 toys so each child gets one toy at least**. we are now left with **2 toys** to distribute among **9 children**.
$$=\binom{2 + 9 - 1}{ 9 - 1}$$
$$=\binom{10}{8} $$
$$=45$$
=> There is **165 ways** to distribute the toys so each child gets at least one toy, for the balloons, **since they are identical, order doesn't matter so using combination,**
$$=\binom{16}{9}$$
$$=11440$$
=> Total ways to distribute the balloons and toys
$$= 45 + 11440$$
$$ = 11485  $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Balloons:**

If $x_k$ denotes the number of balloons received by the $k$th child, then 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 + x_7 + x_8 + x_9 = 16 \tag{1}$$
The number of ways the balloons can be distributed is the number of ways equation 1 can be solved in the nonnegative integers.  A particular solution corresponds to the placement of eight addition signs in a row of sixteen ones.  For instance,
$$1 1 1 + 1 + 1 1 + + 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 + + 1 1 1 + 1$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 3$, $x_2 = 1$, $x_3 = 2$, $x_4 = 0$, $x_5 = 4$, $x_6 = 2$, $x_7 = 0$, $x_8 = 3$, $x_9 = 1$.  The number of such solutions is the number of ways we can fill eight of $24$ positions (for $16$ ones and $8$ addition signs) with addition signs, which is 
$$\binom{16 + 9 - 1}{9 - 1} = \binom{24}{8}$$

**Toys:**

We have $11$ different toys to distribute to nine children, subject to the restriction that each child receives at least one toy.

*Method 1*:  Notice that either one child receives three toys and the others each receive one or two children receive two toys and the others each receive one.

One child receives three toys and the others each receive one:  There are nine ways to select the child who receives three toys and $\binom{11}{3}$ ways to choose the toys that child receives.  The remaining eight toys can be distributed to the remaining eight children in $8!$ ways.
$$9\binom{11}{3} \cdot 8! = 9!\binom{11}{3}$$

Two children each receive two toys and the others each receive one:  There are $\binom{9}{2}$ ways to select the children who receive two toys, $\binom{11}{2}$ to select two toys for the younger of the selected children, $\binom{9}{2}$ ways to select two of the remaining $11 - 2 = 9$ toys for the older of the selected children, and $7!$ ways to distribute the remaining toys to the remaining seven children.
$$\binom{9}{2}\binom{11}{2}\binom{9}{2} \cdot 7!$$

Total:  $$9!\binom{11}{3} + 7!\binom{9}{2}\binom{11}{2}\binom{9}{2}$$

*Method 2*:  If there were no restrictions, we would have nine choices for each of the eleven toys, which would yield $9^{11}$ ways to distribute the toys.  However, we must exclude those distributions in which at least one child does not receive a toy.  There are $\binom{9}{k}$ ways to exclude $k$ children from receiving a toy and $(9 - k)^{11}$ ways to distribute the toys to the remaining children.  By the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the number of ways of distributing the toys so that each child receives at least one is 
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{9} \binom{9}{k}(9 - k)^{11} = 9^{11} - \binom{9}{1}8^{11} + \binom{9}{2}7^{11} - \binom{9}{3}6^{11} + \binom{9}{4}5^{11} - \binom{9}{5}4^{11} + \binom{9}{6}3^{11} - \binom{9}{7}2^{11} + \binom{9}{8}1^{11} - \binom{9}{9}0^{11}$$

**Total:**  Since the balloons and toys can be distributed independently of each other, the number of ways to distribute the balloons and the toys given that each child receives at least one toy is 
$$\binom{24}{8}\sum_{k = 0}^{9}\binom{9}{k}(9 - k)^{11}$$